# Fearless and priceless

Tags: word-usage

In' Fearless, painless and harmless"less" means "without" and in' priceless' it means too precious to be priced,the opposite of 'worthless'. Can we express the idea "without price" other than the way 'free of cost' or 'cost free' ?

Comment: I suspect that the distinction between *priceless* and *worthless* may be more a matter of usage rather than logic.

Comment: *Cost* and *price* are not synonyms.  *Cost* is how much the buyer must pay, *price* is how much the seller requests. There is often a connection between a price and a cost, but not always. If you were to buy my house, it would cost you some amount of money. But I am not selling my house, so it has no price.

Comment: @Juhasz Very well put. And 'worth' has yet another meaning to 'price' and 'cost' as any economist will confirm. "Priceless" simply means that something is so good that no owner would be prepared to put a price on it - like your house!

Comment: If the OP wishes to express "without price", consideration has to be given as to why. If it is simply that no one has got round to affixing a price tag, then the goods are said to be "un-priced".

Answer (score 1):

Priceless and fearless are exactly the same(in regards to the suffix less), as are your other examples, because less translates better to *"have no"* and not *without*.

as in:

- He has no fear -> He is very courageous(or very stupid; depends of the point of view).
- It has no price -> Nothing can buy it.

  It differs from free, in that free doesn't mean it has no price. it means *you are free* to get it (from this specific vendor or what have you).

So you can see now why free and priceless are very different, and why "without" cost is not the same as free of cost or cost free.

If you are looking for other words for **free**, then you might use:

- complimentary
- freebie
- gratuitous
- for nothing

and other synonyms (dictionary.com)

for **priceless**:

- incalculable
- invaluable
- irreplaceable

and other synonyms (dictionary.com)

Different roots of the word create different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that *priceless* means *without* in the sense of, "can't put a price on it." There's also irreplaceable, one-of-a-kind, and invaluable.

Comment: You're welcome. And another way to describe it --- we can't put a price on it because "all the money in the world wouldn't be enough". Priceless has that connotation: there's only one, and no way to make another, and it's just way awesome for some reason. It's also used for someone's joke or comment: "What she said to the waiter - it was priceless!" ...meaning perfectly funny or sarcastic in that moment.